# Button with background gradient and image using html and css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a button with gradient background and an image. This is what I have so far:

[**jsfiddle/D6xKD/**](http://jsfiddle.net/D6xKD/)

If you look at the button you can see that the gradient is only working around the image and not throughout the button.

Note: This solution I fetched from other references about a button with gradient background and background image.

My question is: How to get the gradient and image working for cross browsers including ie7 and above?

HTML:

```
<button class="button" onclick="submit();" type="button">Text button</button>
```

CSS:

```
.button{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 9px 36px 9px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:4px auto auto;
    cursor:pointer; 
    border:0px;
    background: #3ba93d;
    background-position: 66px 4px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/mw5HWR); /* fallback */
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/mw5HWR), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3ba93d), to(#27842a)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/mw5HWR), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/mw5HWR), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* FF3.6+ */
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/mw5HWR), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* IE10 */
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/mw5HWR), -o-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/mw5HWR), linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* W3C */
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove `background-position`

Comment: why so complicated? simply use an image within the gradient

Comment: yes, i agree with @chrisツ , u need not use all those complicated things. Just use normal `linear-gradient()` and remove the `background-position`. That's it :)

Comment: Alright, so i fixed it, all i had to do is to change the values of background position from 'background-position: 66px 4px;' to 'background-position: center right;'. The purpose of 'background-position' here was used to set the image on right side of the button. Thanks for the tips :)  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/D6xKD/11/)

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/D6xKD/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could try:

```
        <button class="button" onclick="submit();" type="button">Text button <span></span></button>

        <style>
        .button{
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 0;
            padding-left: 20px;
            height: 36px;
            width: 120px;
            margin:4px auto auto;
            text-align: left;
            cursor:pointer; 
            border:0px;
            background: #3ba93d;
            background-position: 66px 4px;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background: #3ba93d; /* fallback */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3ba93d), to(#27842a)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* IE10 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* W3C */
            }
          .button span {
            position: absolute;
            top: 17px;
            left: 100px;
            width: 20px;
            height: 24px;
            background: url(http://goo.gl/mw5HWR);
          }
           </style>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simondavies/SrFGy/)

Comment: Thanks for this technique of having a separate function for the image in the button. It really worked out well with ie 7 and above compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @simon-davies answer

you also can ommit the "span" element :

```css
.button{
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 0;
            padding-left: 20px;
            height: 36px;
            width: 120px;
            margin:4px auto auto;
            text-align: left;
            cursor:pointer; 
            border:0px;
            background: #3ba93d;
            background-position: 66px 4px;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background: #3ba93d; /* fallback */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3ba93d), to(#27842a)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* IE10 */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(top, #3ba93d, #27842a); /* W3C */
            }
          :before {
            content : "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 17px;
            left: 100px;
            width: 20px;
            height: 24px;
            background: url(your_image_url) no-repeat;
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This style is pushing the gradient over:

```
 background-position: 66px 4px;
```

If you remove it, the gradient fills the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/D6xKD/9/

If you need the apple to be in a certain position, I'd recommend expanding the canvas of your image to help in its placement.

Comment: Solved. See my comments :) Thanks for suggestion. [jsfiddle.net/D6xKD/11](http://jsfiddle.net/D6xKD/11/)

Comment: Cool! I'm unsure why background gradients were lumped in with background images, glad you got it working!

Comment: Thanks. As I understand, the gradient was positioned with the image as both are the background properties and background-position sets the position for all backgrounds within the function (class or id). Also, talking about compatibility, the solution provided by Simon is good as it keeps the image even on ie7, 8 and 9.